# touchpad not recognised in xinput, ubuntu18

Tags: touchpad, xinput

i buy a hp envy x360, i5 1135g7, and everything works well in win10. but touchpad and touchscreen cannot use at all in ubuntu18LTS, input xinput, it comes out no touchpad, which fail to recognise touchpad device. how fix it without update kernel?(newest kernel might work well? but i need use some old codes)
thank you.

```
uname -a
Linux hp-envy 5.4.0-54-generic #60~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 17:25:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: It means that the touchpad is not supported by this kernel.

Comment: thankyou, it seems that updating kernel is the only risky way that i wonnt take.